# XercesImpl.jar nullpointer exception in weblogic 11g

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, weblogic, xerces

Why does XercesImpl.jar cause nullpointer exception when a web application is running in weblogic if it is present in the lib folder of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be conflicting with the XML Parser library that is included with WebLogic.  Try using the ClassLoader Analysis Tool to see if there is a conflict.

What version of WLS are you running?  10.3.what?

Comment: I am using 10.3.3. Thanks for the explanation.